# for rxjs observerable how to do APIs fetch, which only after the first API complete and go to execute the second APIs

Tags: rxjs, fetch, observable

I have lists of APIs urls. I want to put them as pipe observable objects and fetch data from those APIs, But my requirements is only after the first urls fetched successful and continue to fetch the second APIs data.

I know I can ure rxjs from:

```
from([url1, url2, url3...]);
```

change the list to observable, but I do not know how to make this object only after the first element fetching is finished to fetch the second element data and so on.

I do not know how to construct this loop or a similar recursive function.

[update]

Thanks for rad11 comments, I try to use concatMap, but it is do nothing as my fellow code:

```
downloadmat(urltext:string):any{

let index = urltext.lastIndexOf('/');
let filename = urltext.slice(index+1).split('?')[0];
fetch(urltext).then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = filename;
  link.click();
})
.catch(console.error);
}

triggerdownload(){
console.log("=======here========");
  from([this.url1,this.url2]).pipe(concatMap((url)=>this.downloadmat(url)));
}
}
```

the main function is triggerdownload(), I try to download urls. but it only print result not trigger download contents.

Comment: Use switchMap in pipe this will do it in sequence

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right, in rx terms I would put it like this:

- you start from an array of urls which you need to convert to a stream
- then you take each notification of this stream (i.e. each url) and turn it into another Observable which represents a call to the API represented by the url (i.e. you call the endpoint with the url)
- and then you want to trigger the execution of these Observables one after the other, as a concatenation

If this is true, then the code could look like this

```
// with the from function you turn an array into a stream, in this case of urls
from([url1, url2, url3...])
// with pipe you start the transformation pipeline
.pipe(
   // you turn the url into a fetch Observable which notifies when the fetch operation completes 
   // and concatenate the execution using the concatMap operator
   concatMap(url => fromFetch(url)),
).subscribe()
```

In this way you execute one fetch after the other, in other words only one request is on fly at a time, which means that the concurrency is 1.

If you need a different concurrency threshold, you can substitute `concatMap` with `mergeMap`, setting the `concurrency` to the limit you want to reach.

[This blog](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) has some more details about similar patterns that involve rxJs and http.

Comment: I update my download function, it does not work for download content.

Comment: @user504909 in my answer, I actually forgot to `subscribe`. I have updated my answer. Now, assuming that the function `downloadmat` actually works, I think the code I have suggested should work. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-perue1?file=index.ts) for an example where `downloadmat` is simulated